# How can I safely initialise a constant of type `NonZeroU8`?

Tags: rust, constants

The constructor of `NonZeroU8` is a `const fn`, but it returns an `Option`, and `Option.unwrap()` is not a `const fn`, so the following won't compile:

```
use std::num::NonZeroU8;

const _: NonZeroU8 = NonZeroU8::new(7).unwrap();
```

The best work-around I've found is:

```
use std::num::NonZeroU8;

const _: NonZeroU8 = unsafe {NonZeroU8::new_unchecked(7)};
```

The use of "unsafe" is unsatisfying. Is there a safe way?

Comment: IMO, this is the most benign kind of `unsafe`: there's only one invariant that `new_unchecked` requires, and it's true by inspection; you don't need to look anywhere other than this one line to verify its correctness. Therefore I would just use `unsafe` here (at least until compiler improvements allow us to call `new` in a `const` context). Good Rust code will use `unsafe` occasionally where it makes sense to do so; using an awkward workaround to avoid `unsafe`, when it's trivially correct to do so, doesn't make the code better. YMMV.

Comment: @trentcl It's even safer than that, since it being used in a `const` expression means that even if it's used incorrectly, the compiler will error at compile time. It just comes down to stylistic preferences, or I guess if you want your code to contain absolutely zero uses of `unsafe`. ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ca1826ee71e02f85c7d6080f3113d1ef))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Panicking in `const` fns is currently unstable, which is why you can't use `unwrap`. A somewhat ugly, but stable workaround without using `unsafe` is to use something that implicitly panics, like out-of-bounds array indexing:

```
use std::num::NonZeroU8;

const VALUE: NonZeroU8 = match NonZeroU8::new(5) {
    Some(v) => v,
    None => [][0],
};

fn main() {
    println!("Value: {}", VALUE);
}
```

You can test this and note that changing the `5` to a `0` will cause a compile-time error. It's worth noting that within constants, `new_unchecked` will still cause compile-time errors for zero values, so it's fine to use that despite the `unsafe`.

Comment: this remind me the famous boost trick in C++ :p